# PowerShell User Input, Menu, Sub Menu,

Tags: powershell, parsing, menu

I'm trying to create an interactive PowerShell script that will do the following:

Menu 1 - Prompt user for file path. Then based on file path I will cd into the directory

Menu 2 - Once user input is done I would have a second menu that would prompt user to pick which file to parse

One user selects option it will output file and then restart from Menu 2

I'm not understanding how to only show the first menu, then once user input is submitted jump to second menu, and once user selects and file is parsed - come back to second menu until "Q".

```
$Filepath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter File Path'
do
cd $FilePath

function Show-Menu {
    Clear-Host

    Write-Host "1: Press '1' for parsing test.txt"
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' for parsing test2.txt"
    Write-Host "3: Press '3' for parsing test3.txt"
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}

do {
    Show-Menu $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
    switch ($selection) {
        '1' {
            'You chose option #1'
            Clear-Host
            Import-Csv txt.file -Delimiter '|' -Header '1' ,'2' | Out-GridView
        }
    }
    pause
} until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a loop, the other option is to have the 'menu' function call itself to show the menu again after you've completed the parsing.

You could also use `Host.ChoiceDescription` to build and show the menu for you.

```
$Filepath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter File Path'
Set-Location $FilePath

function Get-Selection {
    $Title = "Please make a selection"
    $Message = "Select File for parsing"
    $Option1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "test.txt"
    $Option2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "test2.txt"
    $Option3 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "test3.txt"
    $Option4 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Quit"
    $Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Option1,$Option2,$Option3,$Option4)

    $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)
}

function Show-Menu {
    switch (Get-Selection) {
        0 {
            Write-Host 'You chose option #1'
            Clear-Host
            Import-Csv txt.file -Delimiter '|' -Header '1' ,'2' | Out-GridView
            Show-Menu # Show menu for next choice
        }
        1 {
            Write-Host 'You chose option #2'
            Clear-Host
            # Import-Csv
            Show-Menu # Show menu for next choice
        }
        2 {
            Write-Host 'You chose option #2'
            Clear-Host
            # Import-Csv
            Show-Menu # Show menu for next choice
        }
        3 {
            Write-Host 'Quit'
        }
    }
}

Show-Menu # Load menu when script is run
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have two menus in your post. You only have one. Unless you are saying you are considering that Read-Host a menu.

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
Clear-Host

$Filepath = Read-Host -Prompt "`nPlease Enter File Path"
Push-Location -Path $Filepath


$MenuOptions = @'
"Press '1' for parsing test1.txt"
"Press '2' for parsing test2.txt"
"Press '3' for parsing test3.txt"
"Press 'Q' to quit."
'@

"`n$MenuOptions"

while(($selection  = Read-Host -Prompt "`nSelect a option") -ne 'Q')
{
    Clear-Host

    "`n$MenuOptions"

    switch( $selection )
    {
        1 { 'Code for doing option 1 stuff' }
        2 { 'Code for doing option 2 stuff' }
        3 { 'Code for doing option 3 stuff' }
        Q { 'Quit' }
        default {'Invalid entry'}
    }

    Pop-Location
}
```